# Is there a way to decode gRPC response into JSON?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, grpc, grpc-web

I am creating a chrome extension to debug all the gRPC calls in a good way.
Until now I tried:

```
JSON.parse(body.toString())
```

```
atob(body)
```

But non of it is working.

So my question is: **Is there a way to decode gRPC response into JSON?**